# need Joomla component to Add video from blip.tv and video from youtube

Tags: video, joomla, content-management-system, joomla-extensions

need a video component in which i can create category and sub category and integrate video from youtube or blip.tv

can you please tell me about the best component to organise video

regards

Hasnain

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most feature rich component written natively for joomla is hwdvideoshare and you may get it from [here](http://hwdmediashare.co.uk/downloads/category/7).Features are indicated [here](http://hwdmediashare.co.uk/hwdvideoshare)

[Kaltura Community Edition](http://www.kaltura.org/project/community_edition_video_platform) is a very advanced php-based Video application which is not natively written for joomla but you can find a joomla integration component on [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-display/10872?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czo3OiJrYWx0dXJhIjtpOjE7czo5OiJrYWx0dXJhJ3MiO30=).Kaltura is probably for power users.first check out hwdvideoshare and if it didnt satisfy you try using kaltura

#### Kaltura Community Edition is ideal for:

Publishers that want to host the video platform and content at their own datacenter or on the cloud

Service providers or web-developers that want to provide video management and delivery solutions to the web sites that they build or provide services for

ISV and Platform developers that want to integrate video into their platform, adding video management and delivery to the platform offering

CDNs, ISPs and hosting providers that want to add video management and delivery services to their offering

Enterprises that want to manage video and rich media content behind the firewall

Universities that want to manage video in conjunction with their LMS, or a campus wide video portal

Any site - combined with Kaltura’s extensions for leading CMS and LMS platforms (including Drupal, Joomla, Moodle, Sakai, Blackboard and Wordpress)

Check out their [joomla demo site](http://joomla.kaltura.org/)